# What is the difference between `;` and `,` in typescript type/interface definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried them both and they both work for types and interfaces too.

```ts
// Types

type TA {
  a: string,
  aa: number
}

type TB {
  b: string;
  bb: number;
}

// Interfaces
interface IA {
  a: string,
  aa: number
}

interface IB {
  b: string;
  bb: number;
}
```

So is there any difference between `,` and `;` and which of them should I prefer?

Comment: The [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) uses semicolons, not commas. I only ever see commas used in [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based, but man, even though `;` works, it just goes against all conventions for arrays/objects that I've ever seen...

Comment: @TimLewis it maybe opinion-based but it doesn't hurt to inform what the vast majority of tooling uses.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh yeah, for sure! And posting that as a comment is perfectly fine :)

Comment: I have only see commas in enums, even my eslint shows warning if commas are used and my eslint is configured to use airbnb styling which is somewhat industry standartd these days